# The Diophantine equation $x^2 + bxy + cy^2 = p^z_1 \cdots p^{z_k}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be given primes. Is there an effective algorithm to find all the solutions of the Diophantine equation $$x^2 + bxy + cy^2 = p_1^{z_1} \cdots p_k^{z_k}$$ in $(x,y,z_1,\ldots,z_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^{k}$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$?

Comment: Yes: $x=1$ and everything else is 0.

Comment: @eric : Naturally, I meant to find all the solutions. Not just one of them. The question has been edited to clarify this.

Comment: If the left-hand side is irreducible over the rationals and you go to the quadratic field where it factors, then you are looking at the $S$-units of that field where $S=\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$ and the generalization of the Dirichlet unit theorem to $S$-units describes all the solutions.

Comment: It seems difficult to imagine an algorithm which could enumerate such a possibly infinite set. Certainly there is a very simple algorthim which will find all solutions given an infinite amount of time.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch  That's true. And if you want to compute them you are looking at linear forms in logarithms. But I have a feeling that this should be simpler than the Thue-Mahler equation where the left-hand side is a homogeneous polynomial in x,y of degree at least 3. Perhaps it's just that you can use Davenport's lemma rather than linear forms in logs and LLL reduction. In any case, I can't find a reference and I'd like to.

Comment: @DanielLoughran : With the condition (x,y)=1, I am pretty sure the solution set is provably finite. (If the homogeneous polynomial on the left-hand side was irreducible of degree larger than 3, it's called a Thue-Mahler equation and it's well-known there is an effective algorithm to determine the finite number of solutions).

Comment: Why do you need linear forms in logs? Also if $b=0,c=-2$, there are infinitely many solutions with $z_i=0$, for example.